# Passing JS settings local to an instance of a field

Tags: 7, javascript

When attaching a behavior to an object there are two parameters, context and settings. As I understand, settings object is global to all the page. But what to do if I need to send different settings to different widget instances on a single page?

Comment: This might give you some feedback (a year later) - http://blog.amazeelabs.com/en/comment/293144